JAX-RS HTTP Proxy setup
We have a client that is setup for JAX WS and JAX RS client code.
We need use a http proxy and have setup tomcat jvm arg .
The JAX WS code is working for external api that needs to go via the proxy.
-Dhttp.proxyHost= 
-Dhttp.proxyPort= 
-http.nonProxyHosts="*.a.com|localhost" 
-Dhttps.proxyHost=
-Dhttps.proxyPort=
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes="" 
-Djdk.http.auth.proxying.disabledSchemes=""

For the JAX RS code we are getting this error. We are setup for javax.ws.rs-api  2.1 and for this customer we have setup jersey 2.36. Without using jersey specific code can we get the proxy to work ?
The API failure are for internal API that needs to bypass the HTTP Proxy (nonProxyHosts)
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 502 cannotconnect"
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:269) ~[jersey-client-2.36.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:297) ~[jersey-client-2.36.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$invoke$0(JerseyInvocation.java:662) ~[jersey-client-2.36.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.call(JerseyInvocation.java:697) ~[jersey-client-2.36.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.lambda$runInScope$3(JerseyInvocation.java:691) ~[jersey-client-2.36.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292) ~[jersey-common-2.36.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274) ~[jersey-common-2.36.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:205) ~[jersey-common-2.36.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:390) ~[jersey-common-2.36.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.runInScope(JerseyInvocation.java:691) ~[jersey-client-2.36.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:661) ~[jersey-client-2.36.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:439) ~[jersey-client-2.36.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:345) ~[jersey-client-2.36.jar:?]


